# Repository Class Delegation to Multiple Daos that implement BaseDao - Possible?

Tags: generics, kotlin, android-room

I've got a Room database for my Android application. My FooDao and BarDao both implement BaseDao:

```
interface BaseDao<T> {
    @Insert
    fun insert(obj: T): Long
    @Update
    fun update(obj: T)
}

@Dao
interface FooDao: BaseDao<FooEntity> {
    @Query("some query")
    fun doSomethingWithFoo()
}

@Dao
interface BarDao: BaseDao<BaseEntity> {
    @Query("some other query")
    fun doSomethingWithBar()
}
```

I have a repository class as well:

```
class MyRepo(private val fooDao: FooDao, private val barDao: BarDao) {
    fun doSomethingWithFoo() = fooDao.doSomethingWithFoo()
    fun doSomethingWithBar() = barDao.doSomethingWithBar()
}
```

But imagine that FooDao, BarDao, and MyRepo have many more than just these two functions.

I have learned about class delegation to enable compositional inheritance. I am thus trying to reduce boilerplate in MyRepo by having it delegate simple functions that just call a dao's function and return the dao's return value. It makes sense that I should do:

```
class MyRepo(...): FooDao by fooDao, BarDao by barDao {
    //fun doSomethingWithFoo no longer necessary
    //fun doSomethingWithBar no longer necessary
}
```

However, Android Studio gives me the red squiggly saying `Type parameter T of BaseDao has inconsistent values: FooEntity, BarEntity`

Does this mean all hope is lost for reducing all this boilerplate like `MyRepo.doSomethingWithFoo = fooDao.doSomethignWithFoo`? Or is there a way to accomplish this?

I tried to actually override the BaseDao functions in MyRepo thinking it would stop complaining about FooEntity and BarEntity:

```
class MyRepo(...): BaseDao<Any>, SetDao by setDao, ... {
    override fun insert(t: Any): Long = 0L
}
```

but that just adds "Any" to the inconsistent types message.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and replaced generic classes by annotations.

We recently published our library [LivingRoom](https://github.com/msbelaid/LivingRoom)

You just have to mark your entity class with the appropriate annotation (@Insertable, @Deletable, @Updatable, @Selectable ...)